# Creating a new thread to save object to file

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I want to save an object (my game's model/data) to disk, but as the game can get quite large - feasibly large enough to take several game ticks to store - I'm thinking it makes sense to perform the saving in a separate thread in order to keep the game running relatively smoothly.

What is the best method to achieve this? I wasn't sure if it made sense to make the GameState (the model) a runnable or an extension of Thread, because most of the time it isn't intended to be Runnable - logically, then, it shouldn't be Runnable?

Other possibilities I've looked at are to have a Runnable GameSaver class, to which I pass the GameState or a copy of the GameState. Presumably, however, this would cause problems with synchronisation if I pass the GameState or will slow the game down while the class is cloned.

What's the best approach, or the pro's and con's of approaches? Any other alternatives appreciated, too - I doubt my search has been exhaustive.

Comment: You will have to solve synchronisation, whatever solution you choose.

Comment: I can't see how you can safely write the state without taking a snapshot.

Comment: @Martin James It depends on how your state is organised. If, for example, you store timestamped events, you don't have to. (Think of a game of chess.)

Comment: It almost doesn't matter precisely when the save occurs or whether the state changes between clicking save and the file being written. The auto-save can be slightly random, and the rest of the time the user/game only saves when the state is stable (or at least, stable to the point of no important changes occurring) - does that mean I don't need to take a snapshot?

Comment: wrt your side question:  There is almost never a good reason to extend java.lang.Thread.  A Thread is a resource for doing pieces of work.  A Runnable is a piece of work.  It's rare to be creating a new type of resource for doing pieces of work, the ones we have a pretty good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a pure thread management perspective, the cleanest way I think is to use an executor. That does not solve your cloning (or not) issue.

Create a method that saves the game:

```
public void saveTheGame() {
    //you maybe need to take a snapshot, which might require synchronization
    GameState state = ....;
}
```

Create a runnable, as a class instance member for example, that embeds that call and an executor service:

```
private final Runnable save = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        saveTheGame();
    }
}
private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
```

And save the game as and when needed:

```
executor.submit(save);
```

Don't forget to shutdown the executor when closing your app:

```
executor.shutdown();
```

You can also use a `ScheduledExecutorService` instead that runs every x minutes for example.

The class might look like this for example:

```
public static class GameSaver {
    private final Runnable save = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            saveGame();
        }
    };
    private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    private final GameState state;

    public GameSaver(GameState state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public void save() {
        executor.submit(save);
    }

    public static void close() {
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    private void saveGame() {
        //save your game here
    }

}
```

and in your main code:

```
GameState state = getGameState();
GameSaver saver = new GameSaver(state);
saver.save();
```

Comment: I'd completely forgotten the ability to create a Runnable within a class. I'll have to take a look at the ExecutorService, but this looks like a fairly neat technique. What are the benefits of this other than tidiness?

Comment: You don't have to deal with low level details of thread management - although you still need to deal with synchronization if it is necessary. You can change the example easily and use a `ScheduledExecutorService` to auto save every x minutes.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. This looks to be a very neat solution - now I just need to decide whether I need to take a snapshot.

Comment: That really depends on the details of your implementation.